# Module breaks when using a react component within a nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to render a simple nested React component called Navbar but when I use another component (or a Link tag in this case) within it, the console gives me 'Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../Navbar"'.  If I remove the Link tag, the h1 tag is shown and there are no errors.  I can use the Link tag in the App component so I know it should work in the project.

My App.js code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from '../Navbar';
import { RouteHandler, Link } from 'react-router';

export default React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <Link to="about">About</Link>
        <Navbar />
        <RouteHandler />
      </div>
    );
  }

});
```

My Navbar.js code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { PureRenderMixin } from 'react/addons';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default React.createClass({
  mixins: [PureRenderMixin],

  render: function () {
    return (
      <h1>Navbar</h1>
      <Link to="about">About</Link>
    );
  }
});
```

I'm using React-Router, Webpack, and Browser-Sync but besides nested components, routing, building, and syncing seem to be working fine.

Comment: Is  `NavBar.js` located one folder **up** from the `app.js` file? You're using `../`.

Comment: Yeah, components are in separate folders under /components w/ a JS and package.json file. I know it finds Navbar b/c if I comment out //<Link to="about">About</Link> in Navbar everything works fine.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'./components/Navbar'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your render method in `Navbar` is trying to return two values at once, the `<h1>` and the `<Link>`. This is a syntax error. You need to wrap them in a single element, e.g. a `<div>`.

See also http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/maximum-number-of-jsx-root-nodes.html

Comment: Can't believe I didn't realize that. Thanks!